# Router.push is returning my objects as undefined, the array length is correct but the value is "" in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to send data between different pages, and when I try to send two variables, the object is undefined but the string variable is correct. On another page, I follow the same method to pass variables and route pages, and there are no issues passing objects.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import Router from "next/router";

export default function Recipes() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const a = "wjkfhjfkljhfsdjknhsfdkjhn";
  const obj = { a: "b", c: "d" };

  function sendProps() {
    Router.push({
      pathname: "/favorites",
      query: {
        obj,
        a,
      },
    });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <a onClick={() => sendProps()}>Go to Favorites</a>
    </div>
  );
}
```

When I send this data into the /favorites page, the obj is undefined. Why is that?

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

export default function Favorites() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const {
    query: { obj, a },
  } = router;

  const props = {
    obj,
    a,
  };
  console.log(props.a);
  console.log(props.obj);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Recipe</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using the [`useRouter` hook](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/imperatively) in both components?

Comment: @Phil  I am using it, forgot to include it in the question

Comment: No, you're using `Router.push()`, it should be `router.push()`

Comment: @Phil On a previous page i used Router.push() and it worked without issues. I changed to router.push now and it did not fix the issue

Comment: Is the favourites page pre-rendered? From [the documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#router-object)... _"`query`: `Object` - The query string parsed to an object, including dynamic route parameters. **It will be an empty object during prerendering if the page doesn't use Server-side Rendering**."_

Comment: Yes, I suppose it is pre-rendered. It looks exactly as It does from the code I posted above. I do not know how I would server-side render the page, if that is what I must do for the object to not be undefined. @Phil